# Pythonic way of writing a long line of code

Tags: python

```
count_lbl = pd.DataFrame(labels_dataframe.sum(axis=1) \
    .sort_values(ascending=False)) \
    .reset_index() \
    .groupby(0).count() \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename(columns={0:'num_lbl','index':'count'})
```

I am fairly new to Python and i would like to know if this is the best way of writing a long line of code, with multiple sequenced actions on an object.

Comment: You could put parentheses around the expression and get rid of all the backslashes.

Comment: This and @khelwood's suggestion are the two most normal ways to do this. Its also common to use intermediate variables but that kinda defeats the purpose of method chaining. (but they can sometimes enhance readability).

Comment: I like backslashes but its easy to make a mistake. Anything other than the newline after the slash (errant space, comment) is invalid. If you get an inexplicable syntax error on a line with a backslash, check for invisible characters at the end.

Comment: @Tibebes.M The backslashes are actually necessary. I have reverted the change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use left and right parentheses

```
count_lbl = (pd.DataFrame(labels_dataframe.sum(axis=1)
    .sort_values(ascending=False))
    .reset_index()
    .groupby(0).count()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0:'num_lbl','index':'count'}))
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks a lot cleaner! Just to make sure, is this the correct way in terms of indentation?

Comment: I wouldn't say the indentation is incorrect, but there's scope for it to be clearer IMO. Indentation wise it looks like lines 2 and 3 are essentially operating on the same variable, but they aren't.  It's difficult to explain in the format of a comment what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer's approach is to use an extra pair of parentheses. That's fine.

There is also an alternative that just reorganize the lines to take advantage of existing parentheses.

```py
count_lbl = pd.DataFrame(
        labels_dataframe.sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False)
    ).reset_index().groupby(0).count().reset_index().rename(
        columns={0:'num_lbl','index':'count'}
    )
```

In particular:

- Indentation is organized to represent the logical scope, this would address the suggestion mentioned by @Rory-Browne in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364336/pythonic-way-of-writing-a-long-line-of-code/62364432#comment110302268_62364432).
- Line 2 is not currently further split into each function call. But you can easily do that, because they are within a pair of natural parentheses.
- Line 3 does not currently further split each function call. If you really want to, you can bring back that extra outer parenthesis, so that line 3 can be split into smaller snippets. But I think its current form here is good enough, because:

  - If you are going with the fluent API style, those methods are meant to be chained, so, writing them in same line is not a big deal;
  - And, oh, the [chaining style API itself is considered unpythonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Python)